# How to write an OR statement in VBA having large number of conditions

Tags: vba, excel

i am working on a code where i am writing an IF statement. The code goes some thing like this.

```
If Cells(rw, col3).Value = "11312" Or Cells(rw, col3).Value = "21345"Or _
Cells(rw, col3).Value = "176" Or Cells(rw, col3).Value = "134" then
Else
Cells(rw, LC + 2).Value = "WRONG OCC code"
Endif
```

The problem is, i have around 2000 of these OR conditions. When i am trying to put all conditions, VBA is saying too complex code or too much continuation statements. Please help me solve this.

Thannk you in Advance.

Comment: Those numbers do you have them on a worksheet in a column ?

Comment: @lonut i have them in a column but i am making it as an addin so that it can be used in any sheet used by user.

Comment: if you have them on a column you can create a "For" statement and then you will have only 1 condition.If you need help let me know.

Comment: If you have your list of valid codes in a column, hidden within an add-in, you might want to research the `WorksheetFunction.Match` method.

Comment: @lonut thank you very much. I do need help here. But i have one confusion, if i will use the data of that column then if some user is using this addin it will not work for them as datasheet will not be peresent in their local system? Please help me through this.

Comment: @CLR if i attached the column in addin sheet and hide it, then save it as addin. when some other user will install this addin and use in some other excel sheet, will it work ?

Comment: Provided your code references the hidden sheet correctly. It's certainly possible, yes. You might want to consider 'importing' the data from a text file (that all your users can access) for example into your column, each time the add-in initialises. That way, if you need to add or remove codes, you only need edit the text file, rather than publish a whole new add-in each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of your values into a 1D array (choosing however you wish to populate the array) and then test whether they're in the array using the following function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim arr() As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AD")
        arr = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)).Value2)
    End With
    If IsInArray(Cells(rw, col3).Value, arr) Then

    Else
        Cells(rw, LC + 2).Value = "WRONG OCC code"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: the code is working fine. but when i put 2000 elements in array i have to use continuation ( _), but vba throws error of too much continuations after few lines. how can i resolve it.

Comment: Don't populate the array manually like that. Have you got all the values stored in a column? If so which column is it in and I'll update it. Or write the code yourself (you can do it in one line if they're all in the column)

Comment: data is in column A of sheet "AD".

Answer (score 1):

Or simply this...

```
arr = Array("11312", "21345", "176", "134")
If Not IsError(Application.Match(CStr(Cells(rw, col3)), arr, 0)) Then
    MsgBox "Found!"
Else
    Cells(rw, LC + 2).Value = "WRONG OCC code"
End If
```

**Edit:**
If you have a long list of criteria, better list all of them into a Sheet and then read them into an Array.

The following code assumes that you have a sheet called "**Criteria**" and all the criteria are listed in column A starting from row1.

Then you can try the below code to produce the same result...

```
Dim arr
arr = Sheets("Criteria").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(rw, col3), arr, 0)) Then
    MsgBox "Found!"
Else
    Cells(rw, LC + 2).Value = "WRONG OCC code"
End If
```

Comment: the code is working fine. but when i put 2000 elements in array i have to use continuation ( _), but vba throws error of too much continuations after few lines. how can i resolve it.

Comment: How did you manage that to work with the accepted answer then?

Comment: I have edited the solution. See if that is something you can work with.